# AWS Athena timestamp with offset

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

have json in s3 where the time values are given thus :

> 2023-03-26T02:07:34.930000+01:00

I need to convert this local time string into a UTC value.

Thought if I could at least cast to a timestamp value I could then add hours etc
However tried converting into as timestamp with from_iso8601_timestamp but Athena won't let me use that fnct in a create view.
"Unsupported give type"  :(

Obviously I could parse & slice to get the "02" and add "1" (rolling over the day if it's greater than 24, or roll under if adding a negative).

Yet I am hoping that there is an easier 'out of the box' way of dealing with this scenario ?

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on provided timestamp format [`from_iso8601_timestamp`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#from_iso8601_timestamp) combined with `AT TIME ZONE` can be used:

```sql
select from_iso8601_timestamp('2023-03-26T02:07:34.930000+01:00') at time zone 'UTC';
```

Output:

```
            _col0
-----------------------------
 2023-03-26 01:07:34.930 UTC
```

Or you can cast to `timestamp`:

```sql
select cast(from_iso8601_timestamp('2023-03-26T02:07:34.930000+01:00') as timestamp);
```

Comment: That works as stand alone SQL. But when used in CREATE VIEW it returns "unsupported give type : timestamp with time zone.

Comment: @Esby try casting to timestamp - `cast(from_iso8601_timestamp('2023-03-26T02:07:34.930000+01:00') as timestamp)` .

Comment: You just beat me to it ;) Perfect thanks